# python, plotting and c api

Tags: python, c, plot, real-time

I have a little C program that's continuously acquiring a stream of data and sending it via UDP, and in real time, to a different computer. The basic framework for what I originally set out to do has  been laid. In addition, however, I'd like to visualize in real time the data that's being acquired. To that end, I was thinking of using Python and its various plotting libraries. My question is how difficult it would be to let Python have access to what is essentially a first in, first out circular buffer of my C program. For concreteness, let's assume there are 1024 samples in this buffer. Does the idea of "letting Python have a continuous peek at dynamic C array" even sound reasonable/possible? If not, what sort of plotting options are best suited to this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, but not too simple.

You should inform yourself about the [API](http://docs.python.org/extending/) and maybe have a look at some implementations.

If you have done so, you can maybe provide a function which not only gives you a peek at the raw array, but maybe even reassembles it into the right order and length (if it is a circular buffer). This might be very convenient as you nevertheless have to copy the data.

Answer (score 1):

You can quite easily listen to your UDP port with the standard [socket](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html) module.  [Examples](http://wiki.python.org/moin/UdpCommunication) are available.

As a first step, your data could go in a simple Python list, as lists are optimized for appending data.  Removing the first elements  takes much more time, so you might want to only do this from time to time, and only plot, in the mean time, the last 1024 (or whatever) elements of the list.

Plotting can then conveniently be done with the famous [Matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net) plotting library: `matplotlib.pyplot.plot(data_list)`.  Since you want real time, you might find the [animation examples](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/animation/index.html) useful.

If you need to optimize the data acquisition speed, you can have the (also famous) [NumPy](http://numpy.org/) array-manipulation library directly interpret the data from the stream as an array of numbers (Matplotlib can plot such arrays), with the `numpy.frombuffer()` [function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html#numpy.frombuffer).

Comment: Thanks. I've actually stumbled upon a very simple but powerful plotting library that can be called directly from C: [DISLIN](http://www.dislin.de/)

Comment: This sounds like a solution, then!  You might want to write an answer with this and to mark it as the accepted answer.  :)